# serialize object to xml problems

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am having trouble serializing an object to xml.

I have one class that serializs fine:

```
public class GlobalInfo
{
    public string Ripper = "";
    public string Lineage = "";
}
```

I have the code that serializes it here (GlobalInfoData is an instance of GlobalInfo class above)

```
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GlobalInfoData.GetType());
            TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\GlobalInfo.xml");
            x.Serialize(w, GlobalInfoData);
            w.Close();
```

This works fine.

I then have another class:

```
public class Settings
{
    public delegate void SettingsChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event SettingsChangedHandler SettingsChanged;

    #region SoX
    private string sox_path;
    public string SOX_PATH { get { return sox_path; } }

    private string sox_version;
    public string SOX_VERSION { get { return sox_version; } }

    public bool SetSOXPath(string soxpath)
    {

        string sox_result = ValidateSOX(soxpath);
        if (sox_result != null)
        {
            sox_path = soxpath;
            sox_version = sox_result;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            sox_path = "";
            sox_version = "";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string ValidateSOX(string soxpath)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(soxpath).ToUpper() == "SOX.EXE")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = soxpath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "--version";
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.Start();

            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            if (output.Contains("sox: SoX v") == true)
            {
                int i = output.IndexOf("sox: SoX v");
                string version = output.Substring(i + 10);
                return version;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region LAME
    private string lame_path;
    public string LAME_PATH { get { return lame_path; } }

    public bool SetLAMEPath(string lamepath)
    {
        if (ValidateLAME(lamepath) == true)
        {
            lame_path = lamepath;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            lame_path = "";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool ValidateLAME(string lamepath)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(lamepath).ToUpper() == "LAME.EXE")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = lamepath;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.Start();

            string output = proc.StandardError.ReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            if (output.StartsWith("LAME") == true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }


    private string flac_path;
    public string FLAC_PATH { get { return flac_path; } }

    private string default_dir;
    public string DEFAULT_DIR { get { return default_dir; } }
    #endregion

    #region FLAC
    public bool SetFLACPath(string flacpath)
    {
        if (ValidateFLAC(flacpath) == true)
        {
            flac_path = flacpath;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            flac_path = "";
            return false;
        }
    }


    public bool ValidateFLAC(string flacpath)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(flacpath).ToUpper() == "FLAC.EXE")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = flacpath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v";
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.Start();

            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            if (output.StartsWith("flac") == true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public bool SaveSettings()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool LoadSettings()
    {
        return true;
    }
    #endregion



}
```

and the code to serialize it (Settings is an instance of Settings class above)

```
 //Serialization
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Settings.GetType());
        TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(settingspath);
        x.Serialize(w, Settings);
        w.Close();
```

This just creates an xml file containing the xml header but no data. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need read/write properties.

In fact, from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552.aspx

The Serialize method converts the public fields and read/write properties of an object into XML. It does not convert methods, indexers, private fields, or read-only properties. To serialize all of an object's fields and properties, both public and private, use the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: Ah ok yeah I just want to save the values stored, so I should make a class just for holding public data and import/export that?

Comment: @Dave: yeah, you can do that. You have your *working* class that you work with; when you are ready to save you can instance and set the public properties and run that through XmlSerializer. But, that isn't really necessary if you create your *working* class with the appropriate public get/set fields/properties. Use `[XmlIgnore]` on public fields that you don't want XmlSerializer to touch.

Answer (score 0):

For XML serialization to work, you need both get and setters. You have just getters for SOX_PATH and SOX_PATH.

Without these it can't deserialize the objects back from XML.